# Font problems in parsing PDF to text using PDFBox,FontBox etc

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am using **pdfbox api** to extract text from **pdf.**
my program is working fine It is actually extracting text from pdf but problem font of text in pdf is in **CDAC-GISTSurekh(Hindi font)** and output of my program is not in same font it is in **Mangla**.
It is not even matching to text in pdf.
I downloaded same font i.e CDAC-GISTSurekh(Hindi font) and added it in my computer fonts but still output is formatted in Mangla.
Is there any way to change font of output while parsing.

Appreciate any help..

code i have written:

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDocument;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper;

    public class PDFTextParser {
        static String pdftoText(String fileName) {
            PDFParser parser;
            String parsedText = null;
            PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = null;
            PDDocument pdDoc = null;
            COSDocument cosDoc = null;
            File file = new File(fileName);
            if (!file.isFile()) {
                System.out.println("File " + fileName + " does not exist.");
                return null;
            }
            try {
                parser = new PDFParser(new FileInputStream(file));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Unable to open PDF Parser. " + e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }
            try {
                parser.parse();
                cosDoc = parser.getDocument();
                pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
                pdDoc = new PDDocument(cosDoc);
                pdfStripper.setStartPage(1);
                pdfStripper.setEndPage(5);
                parsedText = pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("An exception occured in parsing the PDF Document."+ e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (cosDoc != null)
                        cosDoc.close();
                    if (pdDoc != null)
                        pdDoc.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return parsedText;
        }
        public static void main(String args[]){
            System.out.println(pdftoText("J:\\Users\\Shantanu\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Pdf\\src\\PDfman\\A0410001.pdf"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to read the voterid list.If yes then one thing that I found is that the text is in image format so it is very difficult to parse that.I am also trying to do the same thing.Have you succeed in parsing that.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new PdfStripper Object, user the below syntax and specify encoding for it.

```
PdfTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper(ISO-XXXX)
```

Where (ISO -XXX) is the character encoding used in the PDF.

Comment: Where did you find the code? Is there a way to find out what ISO code the pdf was saved with?

Comment: @Yonkee there is no such constructor available with arg